# Horizontal lines in video playback (all players)

Tags: video

I just installer 11.10 on my brend new machine, which does not have separate graphic card but I have intel i3 2100 and ASUS P8Z68-V lx and everything is fast and I want to watch some movies on my 23" IPS monitor now, but this horizontal lines (appearing sometimes, in all video players) are killing me ?

Can somebody explain me how to solve the problem ?
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might experience a bug related to v-syncing. If you are using unity, try installing ccsm and play around with the v-sync option under opengl settings.

Comment: I am using gnome3

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11682442) on Ubuntu forums might help you. You need to have the compiz settings manager installed. Search for "workarounds" in compiz and tick "Force full screen redraws on repaint" and "Don't wait for video sync".

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.